# I can't create quote line items with community user

Tags: partner-communities, pricebook, quotelineitem, pricebookentry

From a community, I need users to be able to create quotes and their quote line items.

With the community user, I create the opportunity, then I create the quote. Then when trying to create a quotelineitem from the quote's related list, when selecting the pricebook, I get the following error: 'Unable to update pricebook. An error occurred while trying to update the registry. Try again.'

[image]

With an internal Salesforce user, I create a quote line item, and then I try with the community user and I can modify and delete the quote line item but I can't create new quoteline items. It shows me the following error message referring to the Id of the price book entry that I have selected.

[image]

This is the sharing setting I have for the objects.
[image]

I understand that the problem is due to some permission related to pricebook2 and pricebookentry objects.